# How to iterate JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

How can i iterate the following list and print its values?

```
 public class DummyVersions
 {
      public List<string> Version { get; set; }
 }

 [WebMethod]
 public static DummyVersions GetDummyVersions()
 {
      DummyVersions dummyversions = new DummyVersions
      {
           Version = new List<string>
           {
                "1.1.0",
                "1.1.1",
                "1.1.2",
                "1.1.3",
                "1.1.4",
                "1.1.5",
           }
      };
      return dummyversions;
 }
```

```js
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ManagerBaseKit.aspx/GetDummyVersions",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
           $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                alert(); // ??? here i want to print all version one by one
           });
      }
 });
```

Comment: so how can i iterate it?

Comment: It is not clear what ManagerBaseKit.aspx/GetDummyVersions returns

Comment: returns instance of DummyVersions (just a test program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `WebMethod` your resonse is automatically converted to json by ASP.NET, so you can iterate through your versions using the code below:

```
$.each(result.d.Version, function (i, val) {
  alert(val);
});
```

It can be `result.d.Version` or `result.Version` depending on your ASP.NET version more info about that can be found here: [A breaking change between versions of ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)

Comment: True, added some more explanation.

Comment: I dont remember  : 1) can I use GET here ? 2) must I send json ? ( notice : without Scriptmanager attribute !)

Comment: If you use WebMethod you have to use POST and JSON, the response will automatically be converted into to JSON (I was wrong, the post is modified). Use the ScriptMethod to have more freedom.

Comment: When consume asmx  via jquery , must I use [ScriptService] ??

Comment: It is not seems to be working. when i do $.each(result.d.Version, function (i, val) when i debug it, i see that result.d.Version is undefined. If i change it to $.each(result.d, function (i, val) it is iterating every single letter. Moreover, this is the value of result.d: "{"Version":["1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.1.4","1.1.5"]}"

Comment: The GetDummyVersions is still the same as in your question? And what version of ASP.NET do you use?